# How to calculate the most likely mobile robot position based on the distance to nearby objects (walls) which have a known position?

Tags: orientation, robotics, least-squares

I got the distance and angle to the robot from the  detected obstacles (walls) from 2D LiDAR while robot is moving. So now I would like to calculate the most likely robot  pose based on the distance and angle to nearby objects (walls) which have a known position. So if I use the least squares estimator I can get the position of the robot but then how to get the orientation?

For example this gives me the position [robot position estimator using least square method](https://www.th-luebeck.de/fileadmin/media_cosa/Dateien/Veroeffentlichungen/Sammlung/TR-2-2015-least-sqaures-with-ToA.pdf) but then how to get the orientation? Any help?